# View Pagger loads two child data at same time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I Use a Activity that holds a Fragment Inside That Fragment I have an other Fragment that holds ViewPagger2 now when apps open its should display first child of ViewPagger2 and also lode only that data but its not happening its loads two childs that make my app slow how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default behaviour of the viewPager2 to load adjacent pages for smoother animation. But you can override the default offscreen page limit by using viewpager2 `setOffscreenPageLimit` method.

In kotlin use

```
viewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = PAGE_COUNT
```

This will load that specified number of pages in advance. But, this `PAGE_COUNT` cannot be less than `1` which means, It'll still load your second fragment. But, It shouldn't slow down your app as you've mentioned.

If you are doing any network request then you can set `registerOnPageChangeCallback` for viewPager2 and override `onPageSelected`, then do the network request only when that fragment is selected.

As `onPageSelected(position: Int)` only gives us the position of the selected page, but not the fragment itself, so we have to retrieve the selected fragment using `childFragmentManager` and then trigger our network load request.

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                if (childFragmentManager.fragments.size > position) {
                    if(position == 1) { // for second fragment
                        val fragment = childFragmentManager.fragments[position] as SecondFragmentClassName
                        fragment.loadNetworkData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

For multiple fragments you can use `when` statement accordingly.

Comment: it means i add all my network calls in this  viewpagger.registerOnPageChangeCallback section

Comment: No, don't do that. Keep your network calls in their respective fragment. Just trigger them when that fragment is selected.

Comment: how i trrigger them

Answer (score 1):

Put your data loading in the Fragment's `onResume` method as Viewpager2 only resumes the Fragment when it is displayed.

This maintains the Fragment's encapsulation but achieves the same goal as doing it in a OnPageChangeCallback.